# How to indicate if string has numeric value

Tags: vbscript

I loop over string variable `data` which may have integer numeric value, like `"123"`. If this string variable has numeric value, I want to indicate it and thought to use some like this:

```
If IsNumeric(CInt(data)) Then 
    WScript.Echo "Number"
Else
    WScript.Echo "String"
End If
```

But `CInt()` raises error every time `data` variable can't be converted to integer:

`Type mismatch: 'CInt'`

How can I indicate if string has integer value in vbscript?

Comment: Just found out that `CInt()` is not necessary for `IsNumeric()` to function as expected. Removing `CInt()` function is solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[IsNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehs9h2x9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) Function of vb script can be used to determine whether an expression can be evaluated as a number.It returns Boolean value depending upon expression

Please be noted that IsNumeric returns False if expression is a date expression.

Now, in your code you have mistaken that even if it is not number, you trying to convert it into integer

You can use this in your code like  this--

```
If IsNumeric(data) Then       
   WScript.Echo "Number"
Else
   WScript.Echo "String"
End If
```

Comment: I am sure this is a common knowledge but if the string you pass into the IsNumeric() looks like this "1013230924d3" or this "1013230924E3" it will still evaluate to TRUE. D and E are considered scientific notations and things tend to slip through the crack :)

Answer (score 1):

only for integers:

```
If VarType(data) = vbInteger Then
    WScript.Echo "Integer"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Something else"
End If
```

for numbers:

```
If IsNumeric(data)
    WScript.Echo "Number"
Else
    WScript.Echo "string"
End If
```

Comment: For VBScript, which the OP's question is tagged with at least now, one needs to swap `vbInteger` for the number in (for example) [this](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_vartype.asp) page which corresponds to the variable they are looking to check type of.